# Saving mp3 tag data to AWS DynamoDB via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mp3, aws-api-gateway

I tried to save MP3 tag metadata to DynamoDB via API Gateway with a Lambda proxy, but that fails on certain files with:

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
```

The main culprit was the (often present) picture param, which includes a buffer array, which varies in size/length depending on the album art.

What I wound up doing converting the buffer array into a dataURL and storing that in S3, and referencing it in DynamoDB, which works, but results in a lot more API calls and more complexity than just storing the buffer array (converted to base64) in DynamoDB directly.

Has anyone successfully and consistently stored mp3 tag data, including cover art in DynamoDB via the API Gateway, and, if so, how? Or is using S3 the only way to fly with this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really related to MP3, as it applies to all large data you want to pass through API Gateway.

API Gateway has a [limit of 10MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) for the payload size and there is no way of circumventing this limitation.

Even if you'd be able to pass the images through API Gateway, you wouldn't be able to store them in DynamoDB, as each item there has a [size limit of 400KB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-items).

Unless you're open to scaling the images down to <400KB before sending the request, I'm afraid your current solution with S3 to store the images is the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dunedan.  I used the MP3 as it's contextually relevant.  This is chiefly due to the fact that in my tests, the associated album art is usually < 60KB.  One test file that succeeds has an image of 15KB, while another that fails has one that's 52KB.  I believe that the error is actually coming from the json body parser in my Express Lambda function.  Regardless, I'm inclined to agree that using S3 might be the best route here.